# Problem in proof of: Show the order $d$ of $a$ modulo $m$ exists and $d\mid\phi(m)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-order

**Theorem**: Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $(a,m)=1$. Then the order $d$ of $a$ modulo $m$ exists, and $d\mid\phi(m)$.

**Proof**: By Euler's theorem, one has $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, and so the order of $a$ modulo $m$ clearly exists.

Suppose then that $d$ is the order of $a$ modulo $m$, and further that $a^k\equiv 1\pmod{m}$.

Then it follows from the division algorithm that there exists integers $q$ and $r$ with $k=dq+r$ and $0\leq r<d$.

But then we obtain $a^k=(a^d)^qa^r\equiv a^r\equiv 1\pmod{m}$,

therefore $r=0$.

Thus we have $d\mid k$ and in particular $d\mid\phi(m)$

**Point of contention**: I understand that $a^k=(a^d)^qa^r$ and that $a^d\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ since it is the order of $a$ modulo $m$, therefore $(a^d)^q\equiv 1\pmod{m}$.

But I dont understand how $a^r\equiv 1\pmod{m}$

I understand the rest of the argument after this.

Comment: The theorem's statement would be more clear with "the *multiplicative* order $d$ of $a$ modulo $m$ *is well defined*" instead of "the order $d$ of $a$ modulo $m$ exists".

Comment: So obvious, how did I miss that, thanks.

Comment: If you want some easy points, post a brief answer and ill give you +1 and correct answer.

Comment: Substituting $\,\color{#c00}{a^d\equiv 1}\,$ into $\,1\equiv a^k\equiv \color{#c00}{(a^d)}^k a^r\equiv \color{#c00}{(1)}^k a^r \equiv a^r.\,$ Generally if $\,J\equiv K\pmod{d}\,$ then ${\rm mod}\ m\!:\ a^d\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a^J\equiv a^K\pmod m\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(a^d)^q \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ it follows that $a^r \equiv a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, where the second $\equiv$ is by hypothesis.

Answer (score -1):

we have 1=a^d=a^k from def of k,d. And so 1=a^k=a^(dq+r)=a^(dq).a^r=1.a^r=a^r

Comment: Thanks, but try to use Latex and your answer will be clearer

Comment: Have a look at our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math here.